# Load assemblies from another location

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following setup. I have a base MVC application. Which has no controllers or view only a module loader. then I compile a module (seperate) project into the module folder of the main solution whit all controllers and views. these controllers and views use kendo mvc and other assemblies. These assemblies are now copied into this module folder. But I want them into the bin directory of the main solution. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

stupid me :) just set copy to local to false and reference it in the main project